# Youtube theatre mode covered by search bar

Tags: youtube

I have a laptop that I like to watch youtube on while doing other things on my large monitor, but I noticed that when using the theater mode, a significant area of the video is covered by the search bar. On the big monitor it works fine, but I want to use the small one so that I have the big screen free. Is there any way to fix this? Ideally I'd prefer not to use fullscreen because I personally despise it.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the screen where there is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this Chrome extension called Improve YouTube! (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improve-youtube-open-sour/bnomihfieiccainjcjblhegjgglakjdd).

This extension allows you to change a lot of things, including appearance options.

**Step 1**
Select the appearance option from the extension menu.

[image: step 1]

**Step 2**
Select `header` from the appearance menu.

[image: step 2]

**Step 3**
Select position `hover` in the popup dialog.

[image: step 3]

For changes to take effect you might need to refresh the page the first time. If the extension icon is grey the extension settings are not active.